# How to make available more resolutions in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, resolution, vnc

I'm connecting to a computer through VNC and I'd like to fit the host resolution to my computer's.

Is there a way to modify/add resolutions to the list Display Properties Dialog shows?

Thank you!

**EDIT**: The host machine runs Windows XP Home, so it's impossible to use Remote Desktop Connection. On the other hand, the host machine doesn't have a screen attached, so it would be impossible to accept remote assistance requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolutions visible on this list are the ones that can be handled by the graphical card <strike>and the screen</strike> on the computer you connect to.

VNC is not a display manager, replacing the graphical card. It will only copy what you have on screen. As such, you can't change the resolution for something matching to the computer you connect with, if this resolution can't be handled by the target computer. It has to be a valid resolution for this computer, or it won't be displayed.

**Edit:** Ok, in your case, it doesn't depend on screen, indeed, since there is none. I'm not fully sure then how is it handled when there is no screen, if all resolutions from the graphical card are available, or rather almost none.

**Edit2:** Give a try to [PowerStrip](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm). It's not guaranteed that your graphical card will accept it, but if it does, it will allow you to choose any resolution.

Comment: Well, that is the point of my question, the fact is that if I plug in an screen, the available resolutions will change in the way you mentioned, and the resolution I'm looking for will appear, but this is not a solution in my case...

Comment: fyi - the PowerStrip download is blocked by the content filter where I am as a "Malware distribution point." The could mean nothing... or it could mean everything.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Remote Desktop with your Windows machine.  It does display scaling very well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention another possibility:

If you're using Windows on both sides of the connection, Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection lets you use any resolution possible on your local computer (the client).

If the reason you're using VNC is because you have XP Home that doesn't have RDC, then look into Remote Assistance. The difference between it and RDC is that a manual confirmation is required when you connect.